# Why sometimes C-^ is not working as expected?

Tags: key-bindings

I have below mapping in .vimrc.

```
nmap gb <C-^>
```

What I want to do is open a directory, gf to a file, then gb go back to previous directory.

But sometime gb is not working properly. It goes back to another text file instead of previous directory.

Comment: Seems if it's a normal file, gb can go back, but not for a directory, need to figure out how to jump back to a directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is netrw, the plugin which allows vim to browse directories, overrides the `gb` map for its bookmarks feature.

You can disable this by providing a junk mapping in your vimrc:

```
nmap <sid>NetrwBookHistHandler_gb <Plug>NetrwBookHistHandler_gb
```

Or use any left hand side

```
nmap <silent> <f4> <Plug>NetrwBookHistHandler_gb
```

Also, you don't need to use gf to go to a file inside a directory.  Pressing enter works too.